# Inactive state of Iotedge on linux environment according to new release of config.yaml file

Tags: linux, azure-iot-edge

https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/commit/72c11d32f99ae7cb34b3ef41f9346c6249e3ed21
      According to this new released version,I tried for both DPS TPM provisioning configuration and DPS symmetric key provisioning configuration but on providing required configuration,it doesn't work

````
Running "journalctl -u iotedge --no-pager --no-full" gives error:

May 09 14:02:07 mohit2816 iotedged[21270]: 2019-05-09T08:32:07Z [INFO] - Using config file: /etc/iotedge/config.yaml
May 09 14:02:07 mohit2816 iotedged[21270]: 2019-05-09T08:32:07Z [ERR!] - The daemon could not start up successfully: Could not load settings
May 09 14:02:07 mohit2816 iotedged[21270]: 2019-05-09T08:32:07Z [ERR!] -         caused by: Could not load settings
May 09 14:02:07 mohit2816 iotedged[21270]: 2019-05-09T08:32:07Z [ERR!] -         caused by: did not find expected <document start> at line 89 column 6 in etc/iotedge/config.yaml


This the config.yaml file part at line 89:

agent:
  name: "edgeAgent"
  type: "docker"
  env: {}
  config:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0"
    auth: {}

Configuration is as follows:
#Manual provisioning configuration
# provisioning:
#  source: "manual"
#  device_connection_string: "{add connection string}"

```
# DPS TPM provisioning configuration
 provisioning:
   source: "dps"
   global_endpoint: "https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net"
   scope_id: "{DPS_scopeId}"
   attestation:
     method: "tpm"
     registration_id: "{regId}"

# DPS symmetric key provisioning configuration
# provisioning:
#   source: "dps"
#   global_endpoint: "https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net"
#   scope_id: "{scopeId}"
#   attestation:
#     method: "symmetric_key"
#     registration_id: "{regId}"
#     symmetric_key: "{symmetric key}"


Expected output:
● iotedge.service - Azure IoT Edge daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/iotedge.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-05-09 11:15:23 IST; 8s ago
     Docs: man:iotedged(8)
 Main PID: 12540 (iotedged)
    Tasks: 15
   Memory: 10.4M
      CPU: 53ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/iotedge.service
           └─12540 /usr/bin/iotedged -c /etc/iotedge/config.yaml


Actual:
iotedge.service - Azure IoT Edge daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/iotedge.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-05-09 11:57:04 IST; 2s ago
     Docs: man:iotedged(8)
  Process: 13945 ExecStart=/usr/bin/iotedged -c /etc/iotedge/config.yaml (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 13945 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
````

Answer (score 1):

The provisioning section is indented one space too many. This should work:

```
provisioning:
  source: "dps"
  global_endpoint: "https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net"
  scope_id: "{DPS_scopeId}"
  attestation:
    method: "tpm"
    registration_id: "{regId}"
```

Comment: It gives error as iotedge.service: Job iotedge.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.The solution you provided isn't working.

Comment: For me the indentation was indeed the problem. After removing the extra blanks it worked.